# How to pass fields to pentaho update step using metadata injector?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am using pentaho 7.1 which supports metadata injector for update step. Can anyone help me how to pass multiple fields and its values simultaneously using metadata injector

Comment: Are you sure you need a Metadata Injector? According to your screenshot you want to update a field in a table, but this field, FIC_MIS_DATE, is also a key for the update. Please correct your question.

Comment: Corrected the image.I need to do this for multiple tables which is having different columns so i need metadata injector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple streams of data with varying numbers of rows feeding data into the metadata injection step:

- a single row of data to inject single valued things such as the table name or step properties;
- a multi row data stream with the field names to use in the lookup part;
- another multi row data stream with the list of fields to update.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=101&v=EjzgzOanq1o for a tutorial by none other than Matt Casters.

To iterate over multiple tables I suggest you run the transformation multiple times, once for each table to update, fetching the metadata to inject from a text file, or a config table.

Comment: Cannot dream of a better answer, Nelson. I just like minute 4:22, when Matt switches to the Eclipse java code. Nevertheless, the first 4 minutes are enough to get the idea.